# How do I restrict access to admin pages in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need the Django admin interface to be accessible only for superusers and staff when in productions and show a 404 of all other types of users including when not logged in. Is this possible and how?

Comment: I decided to not do the above because staff users may open a link that they should ideally be able to see, but just because they are not logged in, or their session expired, they will get a 404 instead of a simple login redirect. The 404 may not be as important to show for regular users / customers, specially when the modifications that are needed may not be straight forward and might introduce unknown bugs that probably can't all be tested. Django already restricts all admin views by checking if a user is a staff user.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ended up writing a middleware for it:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import Http404

class RestrictStaffToAdminMiddleware(object):
    """
    A middleware that restricts staff members access to administration panels.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith(reverse('admin:index')):
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                if not request.user.is_staff:
                    raise Http404
            else:
                raise Http404
```

Comment: I would suggest raising 403 (forbidden) instead of 404 (page not found)

Comment: Why? I don't want ordinary users to have any knowledge or access to it.

Comment: this does reduce the loading speed drastically because each time a request is sent to the server, e.g for images, etc, it will go to the middleware for verification. Writing a decorator for admin view seems more efficient.

Comment: Maybe remove parenthesis from `user.is_authenticated() ` or an exception raise `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`. This way it worked for me thanks

Answer (score 6):

Overwrite the admin_view part of the AdminSite class before using it in the urls.

In admin.py file (create it if you don't have it) add:

```
from functools import update_wrapper

from django.http import Http404
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect


def admin_view(view, cacheable=False):
    """
    Overwrite the default admin view to return 404 for not logged in users.
    """
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_active and not request.user.is_staff:
            raise Http404()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    if not cacheable:
        inner = never_cache(inner)

    # We add csrf_protect here so this function can be used as a utility
    # function for any view, without having to repeat 'csrf_protect'.
    if not getattr(view, 'csrf_exempt', False):
        inner = csrf_protect(inner)

    return update_wrapper(inner, view)
```

and then in your urls file add:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

from my_project.admin import admin_view
admin.site.admin_view = admin_view

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/login/', page_not_found),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Of course if you still want the login to be found then remove the url(r'^admin/login/', page_not_found) line.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default Django admin pages, Django already has built-in control to restrict access to those pages.  The `is_staff` Boolean for a user model controls whether the user has access to the Django admin pages.  The `is_superuser` Boolean controls whether the user has all privileges without explicitly assigning them.  Note, however, that `is_superuser` will **not** grant access to the Django admin pages; you must set `is_staff` to True regardless of the value of `is_superuser` for a user to have access to the Django admin pages.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff

But I don't know if Django will raise a 404 if a non-staff user tries to access the Django admin interface.

Answer (score 1):

I created an updated version of @ip.'s middleware. This uses `process_view` to directly check if the view is a member of the admin site, rather than just checking if the URL is on the admin site. It also adds a warning log entry if an unauthorized user attempts to access the admin site, and simplifies the `if` logic. This is written for Python 3 and Django 2.

```py
from inspect import getmodule
import django.contrib.admin.sites
from django.http import Http404
import logging 

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class RestrictStaffToAdminMiddleware:
    """
    A middleware that restricts staff members access to administration panels.
    """
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        module = getmodule(view_func)
        if (module is django.contrib.admin.sites) and (not request.user.is_staff):
            ip = request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            ua = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT')
            logger.warn(f'Non-staff user "{request.user}" attempted to access admin site at "{request.get_full_path()}". UA = "{ua}", IP = "{ip}", Method = {request.method}')
            raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own admin_login_required decorator. 
The decorator should check if there is a user and if the user is an admin type. If there is no user, of if the user is not an admin, you can redirect to a login page or display a message saying user is unauthorized.

Here's a good example how to write a decorator for a django view. http://passingcuriosity.com/2009/writing-view-decorators-for-django/

The page described an example of anonymous_required decorator where user has to be anonymous.
You can take that example and implement an admin_login_required decorator using the specs I provided above, or come up with your own scenarios.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package django-admin-ip-restrictor and set ip restriction for Admin view only.

To install package :

```
pip install django-admin-ip-restrictor
```

Exemple in your settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
admin_ip_restrictor.middleware.AdminIPRestrictorMiddleware

]

RESTRICT_ADMIN=True
ALLOWED_ADMIN_IPS=['127.0.0.1']
ALLOWED_ADMIN_IP_RANGES=['127.0.0.0/24']
RESTRICTED_APP_NAMES=['admin']
TRUST_PRIVATE_IP=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of @ip that works(make sure it is after authentication middleware in `settings.py` middleware list)

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import Http404
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
class RestrictNormalToAdmin(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith(reverse('admin:index')):
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                if not request.user.is_staff:
                    raise Http404
            else:
                raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django 4.2 middleware, the function `process_request` is not called anymore. Here is updated version of [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24564941/3139228).

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.urls import reverse


class RestrictStaffToAdminMiddleware(object):
    """
    A middleware that restricts staff members access to administration panels.
    """

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        if request.path.startswith(reverse("admin:index")):
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                if not request.user.is_staff:
                    raise Http404
            else:
                raise Http404

        return self.get_response(request)
```

See also [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/)