# Only staff user should post a product in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend

I am working with an ecommerce app  where everone who login can post their product but I want only staff user to post the product when the staff user is true:
my models.py is:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255 ,unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  #can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  #staff user non super user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  #superuser
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #USERNAME_FIELD and password are required by default
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    object = UserManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.full_name:
            return self.full_name
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self , app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

and my views.py for creating product is:

```
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product-form.html'
    fields = ['title', 'price' , 'status' , 'size' , 'color', 'image' , 'description']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Also I want that if staff is true then navbar show create product for user. right now if user is authenticated navbar show him to post the product

```html
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == logout_url%}active{% endif %}">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ logout_url }}">Logout</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile'%}">Profile</a>
        </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'products:product-create'%}">Create Product</a>
      </li>
      {% else%}
```

Comment: I dont see you checking the `user.is_staff` property anywhere. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not check if `self.request.user` is admin in `ProductCreateView.form_valid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) in your view like this.

```
class ProductCreateView(UserPassesTestMixin,CreateView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product-form.html'
    fields = ['title', 'price' , 'status' , 'size' , 'color', 'image' , 'description']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff
```

And in the template you can test with this `{% if request.user.is_staff %}`

Comment: sir it is working but now it give access the staff user to the admin panel . how to overcome this

Comment: You can check superuser(admin) with `if request.user.is_superuser`  if you only want superuser to access the admin panel @KhîzerKhan

Comment: sir i am new to django and i did not understand . kindly allaborate this

Comment: Are you using django admin panel? If so by default staff user can access the django admin panel but they will not have any permissions unless any permissions assigned by superuser.

Comment: no sir i do not want the staff user to access the admin panel i want him to post the product from frontend only. it is posting   now . but it also have access to admin panel now which i do not want

Comment: You might want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559531/how-do-i-restrict-access-to-admin-pages-in-django

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout the [staff_member_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#the-staff-member-required-decorator) decorator and as already answered, use `{% if user.is_staff %}` in your template for the navigation.